# Extracting specific files with file extension from a .tar.xz archive using MacOS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, tar

I have a number of compressed archives with the extension *.tar.xz*. I am advised that, when decompressed, the total size required is around 2TB.

Within the archives are a number of images that I am solely after.

Is there a method to solely extract files for example with the extensions *.jpeg, .jpeg* and *.gif* from the compressed archives without having to extract every file?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's trivial to just extract one of the file types; for example:

```
tar -xjf archive.tar.xz '*.jpeg'
```

will extract all files with the `.jpeg` extension. It's important to quote the `*`, as otherwise the shell would attempt to expand it, and would only try to match only the files that were found (or fail because there were no files with that name).

You can similarly use other patterns like '*.gif', or both together:

```
tar -xjf archive.tar.xz '*.jpeg' '*.gif'
```

Because you tag that you're using OSX, I'll skip the need to use the `--wildcards` option, which is needed when trying to extract only those files under linux.