# Option not supported in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal, wildcard, tar

I am using Mac OS for my project and I found out that some terminal commands doesn't work which works in ubuntu.
I am confuse why it didn't work because it is based on unix only.
example -

When I run this command on Mac, it gives me

```
tar --wildcards -vf nsx_manager_e80a2842-2460-6f17-1814-adfc81e220a7_20191114_233108.tgz -x "nsxapi.log"
tar: Option --wildcards is not supported
Usage:
   List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
   Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
   Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
   Help:    tar --help
```

Here wildcards is not supported, is there any way we can make these options available on mac terminal. If yes, please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting specific files with file extension from a .tar.xz archive using MacOS terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811165/extracting-specific-files-with-file-extension-from-a-tar-xz-archive-using-macos)

Comment: This question is better suited to [unix.se] than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

`--wildcards` option is only available on the GNU version tar.
If you are using MacOS, you can use the wildcards feature directly without the option:

```bash
tar xvf file.tgz '*/nsxapi.log'
```

or you can install `gnu-tar` via brew:

```bash
brew install gnu-tar
```

then use `gtar` instead of tar as command which supports `--wildcards` option.